# How to set the value from li item into the search field box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I wrote a Bootstrap/jQuery function that when you search for an item, it will bring up the item that matches what you type.

However, after the user finds the item, I am having trouble having it populate the search field or just validating to the user that it was chosen. I added some code, but when I click the box it's in, nothing happens. My end goal is to have it either highlight the box once I hover over it or have it selected once I click in the area.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myList").toggle();

  $("#myInput").on("focus", function() {
    $("#myList").toggle();
  });

  $("#myInput").on("focusout", function() {
    // Here, it'll wait 100 miliseconds to hide the list.
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#myList").toggle();
    }, 100);
  });

  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  // This is the code to populate the field after selecting an option.
  $("li").click(function() {
    var textInfo = $(this).text();
    $("#myInput").val(textInfo);
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="Tabtab1Link">Your boy</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Your boy</a></li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of coordinating events.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
   <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
   <li class="list-group-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1" id="Tabtab1Link">Your boy</a></li>
   <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#">Your boy</a></li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
   <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <style>
  .list-group-item {
   cursor: pointer;
  }

  .list-group-item:hover {
   background: #f0f8ff;
  }
 </style>

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myList").hide();

   $("#myInput").on("focus", function () {
    $("#myList").show();
    search($(this));
   });

   /*$("#myInput").on("focusout", function () {
    // Here, it'll wait 100 miliseconds to hide the list.
    setTimeout(function () {
     $("#myList").toggle();
    }, 500);
   });*/

   $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    search($(this));
   });

   function search(elm) {
    var value = elm.val().toLowerCase();

    $("#myList li").filter(function () {
     $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
   }

   // This is the code to populate the field after selecting an option.
   $("li").click(function () {
    var textInfo = $(this).text();
    $("#myInput").val(textInfo);
    $("#myList").toggle();
   });

   $("*").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (($(this).attr('id') != "myInput") && (!$(this).hasClass('list-group-item'))) $("#myList").hide();
   });

  });
 </script>

</body>

</html>
```